# How to Display full Latin-1 character set (ISO-8859-1) in android textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, textview

Can any one ,how to display  full Latin-1 character set (ISO-8859-1) in android textview

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: I have a text coming from Server,that text i want to display in an Android TextView

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
mIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"));
```

this way, all the incoming strings from the Latin-1 server will be decoded correctly and will be displayed perfectly on android TextViews